Feature request for the Big query UX in developer console
Is it possible to submit a feature request for the big query UI somewhere? I found this: Where to submit new feature request for BigQuery? but I don't see anything about the UI here?

You can submit the feature request for the Bigquery Product by accessing the following link. By selecting the type as a feature request with detailed description.
You can follow the documentation to raise any issue or feature request regarding the GCP products.
